# Инициализация переменной на Net 4.5

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Почему после переноса приложения с net 4 on net 4.5 не удается инициализировать переменную, чего не хватает?

Здесь ошибка

```
ValueCommandLine.MainChannelSending = new ChannelFactory<IWCFService>(
    ValueWCFRequest.MainConfigProtocol,
    ValueCommandLine.MainAddressEndepont);
```

Это настройка параметров

```
public static void ConfigBasicHttpBinding()
{
    try
    {
        ValueWCFRequest.MainConfigProtocol.MaxBufferPoolSize = 7000000;
        ValueWCFRequest.MainConfigProtocol.MaxBufferSize = 7000000;//6250000;6000000
        ValueWCFRequest.MainConfigProtocol.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 7000000;
        ValueWCFRequest.MainConfigProtocol.TransferMode = TransferMode.Buffered;
        ValueWCFRequest.MainConfigProtocol.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
        ValueWCFRequest.MainConfigProtocol.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
        ValueWCFRequest.MainConfigProtocol.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
        ValueWCFRequest.MainConfigProtocol.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
        ValueWCFRequest.MainConfigProtocol.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
        ValueWCFRequest.MainConfigProtocol.Name = "MainProtocol";
        ValueWCFRequest.MainConfigProtocol.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Basic;
    }
    catch (Exception Error)
    {
    }
}
```

и

```
ValueCommandLine.MainAddressEndepont = new EndpointAddress(
    "http://" + ValueCommandLine.IP + ":"
    + ValueCommandLine.Port
    + "/AdministrationServiceManagement/MainEndpoint");
```

**Ошибка**

> System.TypeInitializationException was unhandled
>     HResult=-2146233036
>     Message=Инициализатор типа "System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility" выдал исключение.
>     Source=System.ServiceModel
>     TypeName=System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility
>     StackTrace:
>          в System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceUtility.SetEtwProviderId()
>          в System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory..ctor()
>          в System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(Type channelType)
>          в System.ServiceModel.ChannelFactory`1..ctor(Binding binding, EndpointAddress remoteAddress)
>          в ASAM_Administrator.WCF_Client.ClientRequest.ConfigurationWCFSourceWork(String SelectModule, String[] DataConnect) в C:\Users\user\Desktop\VisualStudio\TerminateProcess\TerminateProcess\WCF_Client\ClientRequest.cs:строка 135
>          в ASAM_Administrator.MainForm.button71_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) в C:\Users\user\Desktop\VisualStudio\TerminateProcess\TerminateProcess\MainForm.cs:строка 7361
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          в System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
>          в ASAM_Administrator.Program.Main() в C:\Users\user\Desktop\VisualStudio\TerminateProcess\TerminateProcess\Program.cs:строка 35
>          в System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>          в System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>          в Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>          в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>          в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>          в System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>          в System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
>     InnerException: 
>          BareMessage=Система конфигурации не прошла инициализацию
>          HResult=-2146232062
>          Line=0
>          Message=Система конфигурации не прошла инициализацию
>          Source=System.Configuration
>          StackTrace:
>               в System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.PrepareConfigSystem()
>               в System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
>               в System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
>               в System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()
>               в System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.get_IndentSize()
>               в System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.InitializeSettings()
>               в System.Diagnostics.TraceInternal.get_Listeners()
>          InnerException: 
>               BareMessage= Неизвестный раздел конфигурации userSettings.
>               Filename=C:\Users\user\Desktop\VisualStudio\TerminateProcess\TerminateProcess\bin\Debug\ASAM Administrator.vshost.exe.Config
>               HResult=-2146232062
>               Line=7
>               Message= Неизвестный раздел конфигурации userSettings. (C:\Users\user\Desktop\VisualStudio\TerminateProcess\TerminateProcess\bin\Debug\ASAM Administrator.vshost.exe.Config line 7)
>               Source=System.Configuration
>               StackTrace:
>                    в System.Configuration.ConfigurationSchemaErrors.ThrowIfErrors(Boolean ignoreLocal)
>                    в System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.ThrowIfParseErrors(ConfigurationSchemaErrors schemaErrors)
>                    в System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem.EnsureInit(String configKey)
>               InnerException:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="NewBehavior0" />
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:8745/AdministrationServiceManagement/MainEndpoint"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BindingRequest"
            contract="TestService.IWCFService" name="MainEndpoint" />
    </client>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BindingRequest" openTimeout="00:10:00" maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                maxBufferSize="65536" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
                <readerQuotas maxDepth="0" maxStringContentLength="0" maxArrayLength="0"
                    maxBytesPerRead="0" maxNameTableCharCount="0" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Filename=C:\Users\user\Desktop\VisualStudio\TerminateProcess\TerminateProcess\bin\Debug\ASAM Administrator.vshost.exe.Config HResult=-2146232062 Line=7 Message= Неизвестный раздел конфигурации userSettings. - скорее всего в приведённом коде нет ошибок.

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос app.config. В исключении явно сказано, что проблема в конфигурации (возможно, какие-то секции перехали в другие места в новой версии фреймворка).

Comment: да вы правы, но все равно не пойму в чем ошибка, я просто сбросил App.config

Comment: Ошибка где то здесь <userSettings>
        <ASAM_Administrator.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="PanelControl2" serializeAs="String">
                <value>Control</value>
            </setting>
        </ASAM_Administrator.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>